# Keycloak Angular - how to handle failed connection to the keycloak

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, electron, keycloak

How to handle the situation when the Keycloak server is not up for whatever reason? I'm using Keycloak Angular in Electron application and I'm getting some interesting results. This is how I'm handlig Keycloak auth:

```
// app.module.ts
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initApp,
  multi: true,
  deps: [KeycloakService, [new Inject(Store)]],
},

//app-init.ts -> factor to chain two initializers
export function initApp(
  keycloak: KeycloakService,
  store: Store<fromApp.AppState>,
): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      initKeycloak(keycloak, restService) // init Keycloak
        .then(() => initNgRx(store)) // then init NgRx
        .then(result => resolve(result))
        .catch(e => reject(e));
      });
    };
}

// keycloak-init.ts
export function initKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService, restService: RestService): Promise<boolean | void> {
 return keycloak
   .init({
    config: {
      url: `http://${KEYCLOAK.host}:${KEYCLOAK.port}/auth`,
      realm: KEYCLOAK.realm,
      clientId: KEYCLOAK.clientId,
    },
    bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets'],
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      checkLoginIframe: false,
      redirectUri: KEYCLOAK.redirectUri,
    },
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('login error:', e);
  });
}

// electron's main.ts
win.webContents.on('will-redirect', function(event, redirectUrl, ...) {
  if (redirectUrl.startsWith('http://localhost:4401')) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const jwt = redirectUrl.replace(/^http:\/\/localhost:4401\/#/, '');

    const newUrl = url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
      hash: jwt,
    });
    win.loadURL(newUrl);
  }

  win.webContents.on('login', function(event, authenticationResponseDetails, authInfo, callback) {
    console.log('login to', authenticationResponseDetails.url);
  });
});
```

Now in the situation when the Keycloak standalone server is not running two situations can happen:

1. When the application is running as a web I'm redirected to `localhost:8080` where it just dies since the server is not running.
2. When the application is running as Electron I can see there's the attempt to redirect to `localhost:8080` when it fails I'm back in the application for a split of a second but then another login/redirect attempt is made which fails again and the application ends up in the infinite loop.

Should I try to ping the Keycloak server in advance and only attempt to login if I have the response? Is there some service or functionality in `keycloak-angular`/`keycloak-js` I'm not aware of?

The plan is that if Keyclaok server is not up I should display special page alerting user of the problem.